# React doesn't fire function in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

LoginPage calls AuthForm  and structure looks like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<any>) {
    return {
    signUpWithEmail: function(email: string, password: string) {
         // bla bla 
     },
 };
}

handleFormSignUpWithEmail(event: React.FormEvent) {
     event.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleFormSignUpWithEmail is fired");
    this.props.signUpWithEmail(this.props.email,this.props.password);
}
render() {
        return (
          <AuthForm onSignUpWithEmail {this.handleFormSignUpWithEmail.bind(this) } />   );
    }
};
```

in AuthForm

```
export interface AuthFormProps {
    onSignUpWithEmail?: (event: React.FormEvent) => void;
}

render() {
    return (
    <button  className="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-pull-right"
      onClick={this.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)}>
        Submit
    </button>
```

This works great, but when I add another function like this, it stops firing  `onSignUpWithEmail`

```
comparePass()
    {
      this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <button className="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-pull-right"
                     onClick={this.comparePass.bind(this)}>
                     Submit
                 </button>

        }
```

why comparePass, cannot fire  `onSignUpWithEmail` ? , the reason I am not doing this in loginpage because I may use authfrom later..

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Try changing `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.apply(this);` to `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this);`

Comment: sorry it is already `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)` I forgot to change it , I was trying to call it with apply or call also

Comment: Is comparePass being fired? try doing console.log() from that function and see if its called, It would have been far better if you had the example setup somewhere.

Comment: yes comparePass is being fired.

Comment: `bind` does not actually call the function. Why do you want to `bind` `this` to a prop'd function?

Comment: well in `render` `this.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)` actually calls the signup function, so I thought just calling `this.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)` in `comparePass` would do exactly same thing, am I wrong? I am brand new to this language and tools, @Jack

Comment: Where in `render`? Your `comparePass` `bind` works in your `onClick` because the click itself is what triggers the function call. What you're currently doing _inside_ compare pass is doing nothing. Either just do `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail()` or `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)()` if you absolutely need to `bind` and call, which you almost certainly don't but there's not enough context to say for sure.

Comment: @Jack `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)();` gave `Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` and I did `this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this)(event);`  and it worked post your answer and I will accept it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're going to do more in `comparePass` but want to pass along the `event` then try:

```
const boundSignup = this.props.onSignUpWithEmail.bind(this, event);
boundSignup();
```